# Can a Dell T110 II Tower server handle the stress of running a website?

Tags: web-server

Just like the subject line says. I've got a website built on C# with SQL Server back end. I'd like to run my own server so I have more control over what I can and can't put on it. It's not going to be Google, but it may get a couple thousand hits per day if I'm lucky. I've got a static IP and a 100MB line leased.

Looking for a reasonably inexpensive server and the Dell T110 II can be had for under $1K. I just want to know if this is realistic, or if it would be a complete waste of money to go this route.

Also, what are recommended minimums for RAM, CPU and such?

Comment: There's 86,000 seconds in a day. A couple thousand hits a day means a hit every 30 seconds or so. Your average smartphone could handle that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

Whether performance will be acceptable depends on your application. Same answer for specifications required (CPU/RAM). Do some performance testing.

Reliability should be considered. Does it have redundant components, like PSU and disk? What if the whole things breaks, will you have a spare? What is the implication of the service being down.

You may be better off using Azure or AWS, which will be more reliable and scalable. A t2.small (2GB RAM, 20% of a Xeon core but burstable, $13/month with a one year reservation) might do it, or a t2.large (8GB RAM, 60% of 2 Xeon cores but burstable, $52/month with a one year reservation). I don't know what Azure charges, but it's probably similar.